# Debezium server configuration for Redis client

Tags: jedis, debezium, debezium-server

I'm running Debezium Server that streams into Redis. I want to pass "socket timeout" and "connection timeout" configurations to Jedis (the redis client that debezium is using), and possible more parameters in future. I didn't find anything in the docs on how to pass those values - is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to do it so I implemented it. [Those configs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.0/operations/debezium-server.html#_redis_stream) are available from version 2.0.0.Alpha2 .